# Unknown entity problem in Hibernate with AnnotationConfiguration

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I've been googling for this problem from last 2 days but havent found any proper solution. I am developing a desktop application with Hibernate. I am using AnnotationConfiguration for registering entities in hibernate. I am not creating xml mapping files as I am using persistence type entity beans. I've tried it with configuration xml file, properties file, programmatic registration of entity beans, but every time i am getting the same exception. 
I've checked the entity class. Its importing javax.persistence.Entity; I've also tried adding @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(mutable=true, dynamicInsert=true, dynamicUpdate=true) but no success.

When I pass incorrect path of one of the entity bean, hibernate initialization fails, which means before changing path, hibernate was picking up a correct entity file.

Is there any way to get a list of registered entities in hibernate configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Have you declared the entities inside Your hibernate.cfg.xml file?

example:

```
<mapping class="test.User"/>
```

Comment: Yes I've already done that. After some analysis, i got to know that the initialization path of entity beans and runtime loading path are different. I am using netbeans platform application and this is the expected behaviour. Can anyone suggest me how can i customize class loading in hibernate? One of the suggestion i got is to customize org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.java
But that file is deprecated in latest release of hibernate.